# How to insert a specific form data to the form textfield of the next webpage using PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

What I want to achieve is to insert the username entered in my "index.html" to the tfUser textfield of my next webpage, named "report.html". I want this to happen because I want to submit the username of the user along with the form data in the "report.html"

I am using 1 MySQL database as a source of my data.

Here are my codes:

**index.html**

```
    <!doctype html>

<html class="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Centro Escolar University - CMT System 2013</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body background="images/bg_new3.png">
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center" class="futuraFont" style="color: #CC0066"><strong>SAMPLE</strong></h1>
    </div>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="loginsub1.php">
    <div data-role="content">   

  <p align="center">
    <label for="userName"><strong>Username</strong><br>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" />
  </p>
  <p align="center">
    <label for="userPass"><strong>Password</strong><br>
    </label>
    <input type="password" name="userPass" id="userPass" />
  </p>
  <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="LOGIN" />
  </p>
</form>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4 align="center" style="color: #666666">FOOTER</h4>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**report.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html class="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Sample Form</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="report.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:1100px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#D6D6D6" background="images/bg_new3.png">
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center" class="futuraFont" style="color: #CC0066"><strong>SAMPLE</strong></h1>
  </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <form id="form2" name="form2" method="POST" action="reportsub1.php">

    <label for="user">
            <div align="center"><strong>User</strong>: </div>
        </label>
          <div align="center">
            <input type="text" name="tfUser" id="tfUser" readonly  onfocus="this.blur();"Required>
            <br>
      </div>
        <label for="tfDate">
          <div align="center"><strong>Date</strong>:</div>
        </label>
          <div align="center">
            <input name="tfDate" id="nowDate" readonly  onfocus="this.blur();"Required/>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                //for getting system time
                function getCurrentTime() {
                    var currentTime = new Date()
                    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
                    var day = currentTime.getDate()
                    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
                    //return (month + "/" + day + "/" + year)

                    if (month<10){
                        var month1 = "0"+month
                        if (day<10){
                            var day1 = "0"+day
                            return (month1 + "/" + day1+ "/"+year)
                        }else{
                            return (month1 + "/" + day+ "/"+year)
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (day<10){
                                var day1 = "0"+day
                                return (month + "/" + day1+ "/"+year)
                        }else{  
                                return (month + "/" + day+ "/"+year)
                        }
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("nowDate").value = getCurrentTime();
                //for getting system time

                </script>
            <br>
      </div>

      <label for="tfDay">
          <div align="center"><strong>Day</strong>:</div>
        </label>
          <div align="center">
            <input name="tfDay" id="nowDay" readonly  onfocus="this.blur();"Required/>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                //for getting system time
                function getCurrentDay() {
                    var d=new Date();
                    var weekday=new Array(7);
                    weekday[0]="Sunday";
                    weekday[1]="Monday";
                    weekday[2]="Tuesday";
                    weekday[3]="Wednesday";
                    weekday[4]="Thursday";
                    weekday[5]="Friday";
                    weekday[6]="Saturday";

                    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];

                    return (n)
                }
                document.getElementById("nowDay").value = getCurrentDay();


                </script>
            <br>
      </div>

        <label for="tfTime">
            <div align="center"><strong>Time</strong>:</div>
        </label>
        <div align="center">
            <input name="tfTime"  id="nowTime" readonly  onfocus="this.blur();"Required/>
          <script type="text/javascript">


                function getCurrentTime() {
                  var d = new Date();
                  function z(n){ return (n<10? '0':'') + n;}
                  return z(d.getHours()) + 
                         z(d.getMinutes());
                }
                document.getElementById("nowTime").value = getCurrentTime();

                </script>
          <br>
      </div>
        <label for="room">
            <div align="center"><strong>Room</strong>: </div>
        </label>
          <div align="center">
            <input type="text" name="tfRoom" id="room" Required>
            <br>
      </div>
          <label for="status">
            <div align="center"><strong>Status</strong></div>
          </label>
          <div align="center">
            <select name="status" id="status">
              <option value="-">--Select One--</option>
              <option value="1">Choice#1</option>
              <option value="0">Choice#2</option>
              <option value="-">Choice#3</option>
            </select>
            <br>
      </div>
          <label for="tfRemarks">
            <div align="center"><strong>Remarks</strong>:</div>
          </label>
          <div align="center">
            <input type="text" name="tfRemarks" id="tfRemarks">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="btSubmit" id="btSubmit" value="Submit Report">
          </div>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4 align="center">&nbsp;</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I use php codes to insert them to my database.

Thank you in advance for those who will help me

Comment: Can you display the PHP code that you are using/written so far?

Comment: your are trying to display php values in html..change report.html to report.php and you can fetch values from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see your form tag in `index.html` that is like follow

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="loginsub1.php">
```

see the `action="loginsub1.php"`. You are posting form to `loginsub1.php`. You can get data in `$_POST` array.  You can set that username value in `session` and then you can get session value anywhere in your web application. For example in `loginsub1.php` you can use

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['username'] =  $_POST['userName'];
```

And in `report.html` (change it as `report.php`) you can access that session value stored in previous page.

```
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" name="tfUser" id="tfUser" readonly  onfocus="this.blur();"Required>
```

Comment: why is it showing me this?
    <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?> instead of the username I entered?

Comment: it is now working, I just changed the files to .php
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user entered in index.php from $_POST['userName'] into session, like this:

`loginsub1.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userName'];
?>
```

Then in your report.html you can do:

```
...
<?php
    session_start();
?>
...
...<input type="text" name="tfUser" id="tfUser" value="<?=$_SESSION['user'];?>" readonly  onfocus="this.blur();"Required>...
```

Check out: [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)